# Why is Desktop directory added to user home folders?

Tags: linux, centos

The server is running Centos 6.6 with no GUI and no desktop. The users are created with:

```
useradd -d /users/$MY_USERNAME $MY_USERNAME
```

I am admin but also have a user account. Even if I delete the empty Desktop directory in my home directory, it is periodically (perhaps daily, I'm not sure) recreated.

Where can I turn this off?

There is only one file under the /etc/xdg path which contains the following:

```
[root@mg01 ~]# cat /etc/xdg/autostart/restorecond.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=File Context maintainer
Exec=/usr/sbin/restorecond -u
Comment=Fix file context in owned by the user
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory may be created by [xdg-user-dirs](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/).

Taken from this [page:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories)

> User directories are a set of common user directories located within the $HOME directory, including Documents, Downloads, Music, and Desktop. xdg-user-dirs is a program that will automatically generate these directories